# The partial view 'First.cshtml' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I'm trying to call partial view in div on click. I've written this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Second", "Second", new AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    UpdateTargetId = "partials",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
})

<div id="partials">
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In my `Index.cshtml.` my controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public PartialViewResult Second()
        {

            return PartialView("Second.cshtml");
        }
```

but my error says that my partial view can't found in:

```
~/Views/switchPartial/Second.cshtml.aspx
~/Views/switchPartial/Second.cshtml.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Second.cshtml.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Second.cshtml.ascx
~/Views/switchPartial/Second.cshtml.cshtml
~/Views/switchPartial/Second.cshtml.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Second.cshtml.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Second.cshtml.vbhtml
```

but I have it in **switchPartial** folder.

If I write `@Html.Partial("Second")` in my div it renders correctly my partial view.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to include the file extension at the end of the partial name. Try:

```
return PartialView("Second");
```

By not including the file extension, each of the registered `ViewEngines` is given its opportunity to resolve the requested view (be in `Second.cshtml`, `Second.vbhtml` or `Second.aspx`).